# Using twisted on OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, twisted

I am trying to use twisted on OS X Mavericks, but I get this error message when I try to import it.

```
christohersmbp2:~ christopherspears$ python
    Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar  8 2014, 09:29:01) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import twisted
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named twisted
```

My guess is that I am receiving this error because I am not using the default Python.  I am using a Python installed with brew.  Ideally, I would want to install twisted into a virtual environment to play with, but the docs are seriously lacking in details.  Apparently, a dmg exists for Mac OS X 10.5, which is not helpful for me.  I can install from the tarball into the virtual environment, but I am not sure how to do this.  Any hints?

Comment: Did you install twisted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using `virtualenv`, it doesn't matter whether you are using the system python or not.

Simply `pip install twisted` in your virtualenv, like:

```
$ workon MyTwistedEnv
$ pip install twisted
```

Currently, [due to a bug in Xcode that affects all projects which contain extension modules](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6974#comment:13), you may need to spell this

```
$ CFLAGS= pip install twisted
```

instead; hopefully this will be fixed soon.  It may not affect brew installed Pythons, however.